# How to share tensorboard running in my localhost:6006 with my collegues?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorboard, tensorflow-lite, embedding

I'd like to share the Tensorboard (Embedding Projector) with my colleagues and I'm trying to find possible ways to share it over the intranet. I can't use an embedding projector since it has sensitive information. Any responses would help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag `--bind_all` to serve on your public network. Then just lookup your computer’s local IP and share it with your colleagues!